# Creation of Stateless Components

Tags: java, wicket

I have created a stateless component in Wicket 1.5, by extending the component and giving the @StatelessComponent annotation,

I was trying to check the component being stateful/stateless with the StatelessChecker.

But i am not able to check, here is the code which i was trying .

@StatelessComponent

**public class StatelessText extends TextField**

//Client Class
StatelessText test = new StatelessText("test");

StatelessChecker sc = new StatelessChecker();

```
  sc.onBeforeRender(test);
```

I dont see anything on console or any exceptions/errors.

Maybe i am not using the correct way, Can anybody please guide me here. 
Appreciate the Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to explicitly call the Statelesschecker in your class. As Throsten said you need to add that in your WebApplications init and annotate your - class to be checked - as Statelesscomponent. If your Application is confidured to be in development mode in you web.xml you will get a runtime error when calling this page if it is Statefull.

Im not sure I understood what you are trying to do there. why are you holding an instance of your class in itself? are you trying to build a singleton? And what purpose does StatelessText has anyway? the Textfield in an usual form will be Stateless as long theres no explicitly added Ajax behaviour to it.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable advise, We are trying to build a framework on top of the Wicket to be used across our application.

Answer (score 1):

you have to register the StatelessChecker during the init of the WicketApplication.

```
/**
 * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#init()
 */
@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();

    // might want to check if you're in dev mode or not...
    getComponentPreOnBeforeRenderListeners().add(new StatelessChecker());
}
```

Comment: Thorsten, I really appreciate your answer. I did what you suggested, but where do get to know that whether given component is stateful/sateless. what onBeforeRender(); will do ? and where can i get the true/false on a given component stateless ( maybe like isStateless() )

Comment: Well if you register the StatelessChecker in your application it will throw an exception for each Component that wicket tries to render and that is not stateless. You don't have to do anything else, just visit a Component that you've declared to be a StatelessComponent

Comment: I am not able to see any kind of exception either in console or in the application, maybe i am not using it as it suppose to be. Could you please explain how to create stateless component and how to check whether it is stateless ?.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Hm this works for me (throws Exception). Have you changed anything in your "StatelessText" class? Because all the Checker does is checking component.isStateless() and tries this also on every child component/behavior.

Comment: OK here is my code.

@StatelessComponent public class StatelessText extends TextField

//class where i am using the statelesstext

StatelessText test = new StatelessText("test"); TextField tf = new TextField("tf");

StatelessChecker sc = new StatelessChecker();
sc.onBeforeRender(test);
sc.onBeforeRender(tf);

now It should throw an exception that TextField is stateful right ? Please correct me.

Comment: Not exactly. "TextField" doesn't claim to be stateless. So it won't throw any exceptions for the normal TextField class. You shouldn't even have to initilize and call the StatelessChecker if you have registered it with your WicketApplication (see my answer). Try to mark the Class you're currently using as @StatelessComponent and then you should get an error that TextField isn't stateless. Because the StatelessChecker will check the Component and all of its childs for statefullness and will see that TextField is stateful.

Comment: Thanks alot for clearing that, So As per my understanding Label,TextField,DropDownChoice,RadioChoice will not be stateful so what will be stateful components. Can you please name them? Appreciate your response and after this I will stop asking questions on this thread.

Comment: Stateful components are those that need the same page instance where they were created for the next request. For example: links, ajax behaviors, form, ...  When you click a Link then it needs to execute its #onClick() method. To do that it fires a request to the server that finds the page that holds this link, then it finds the link itself in that page and then the callback method is executed.